# the setting options in another activity

Tags: android, xml, layout

in my app on the top right of the action bar, I have the setting as three dots (as the usual setting). but when I click on it, it shows a white rectangle that has the word "setting" on it! But I don't want that!! I want just the three dots and when I click it I want it to take me to another activity right away(without showing the option setting on a rectangle). 
this my code for the setting xml:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

The three dots you're talking about are usually there if you don't have enough room in your action bar and you want some of your menu items to show in a menu instead of directly displaying it to the action bar. The best thing for you is to create another item and set `app:showAsAction` to always and call a method using `onOptionsItemSelected` event:

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/your_id"
        android:title="your title"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Call it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.your_id:
            //code here...
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your app has a default menu that has a `settings` item added. You can create your own menu options.

1. Create a new menu.xml file that contains 1 item whose image is the `three dots`.
2. In your class, inside the `onOptionsItemSelected` method, call the activity that you want to open.

Hope this helps :)